# MPU 6050 Pitch and Roll values bouncing back to zero

Tags: mpu6050, arduino-pro-micro

I wired an MPU 6050 to an Arduino Pro Micro:
[image: Wiring]

...and installed the MPU 6050 library by Electronic Cats in the Arduino IDE.

I used the IMU_Zero sketch to capture the acceleration and gyro offsets. I then punched the offset numbers into the MPU6050_DMP6 sketch and uploaded to the board.

So far this is the same procedure explained in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7879Oe71-dY

In the serial monitor I am getting the values for yaw, pitch and roll. Yaw drifts over time, but pitch and roll remain close to zero.

When I move the device to test roll and pitch, the output changes accordingly, but as soon as I stop moving the device, values for pitch and roll change decrease of increase rapidly until they return to zero. It is as if there is a bouncing effect.

I see the same behaviour using the GetAngle sketch from the MPU6050_light library.

This is not the behaviour I see in the video above and several others and I am trying to understand why this is happening and how to fix it. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: There has been 1 open issue (for years now) at the github repository you have chosen for the 6050 driver software regarding a FIFO running out of data and returning zero.  Perhaps you might find an answer there.

Comment: When you stop moving the device, do you lay it flat? If so, this may be intended behavior.

Comment: No, I move the device to a different position and it remains in that position. Yaw value reflects the movement and holds the new position. Pitch and roll do not.

Comment: Your results are unexpected.  Normally Yaw is not something derived from only an accelerometer and gyroscope unless the user is accepting of accumulated errors.  Normally, dependable and steady Yaw requires the user to add a magnetometer. Please check your project's hardware, wiring, power supply, software against working example projects.

Comment: Are you aware that gyroscopes measure *angular velocity*, not orientation? A gyro reads zero if it's lying around. The video doesn't tell much as you don't see the actual movement of the sensor... Though, I'd certainly expect the same behaviour for all three axes...

Comment: You are correct. It is supposed to go back to zero. Actual angles need to be calculated using values from the accelerometer. After doing some more research and testing, I realized my accelerometer is outputting fixed values: 1G for the Z axis, and 0G for the X and Y axes. The values do not change when I tip the board. I used the method described in the video below to test:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VW_XVbtu9k

I have found posts from other people complaining about the high rates of defects on these boards and right now I'm 99% convinced I have a bad board.

Comment: Sketch used for my test: https://github.com/CarbonAeronautics/Part-XIV-MeasureAngles